# Constructor not defined in Test Class

Tags: apex

Thank you in advance

**VF PageName : ObjectAnalysisMultiExport
ControllerExtension  Name: AnalyzeObjMultiExportCtrlExt**

I am receiving Constructor not defined exception, can any one of you please explain

---

```
public class AnalyzeObjMultiExportCtrlExt {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl;
    public AnalyzeObjMultiExportCtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        //controller.setPageSize(10);
        ctrl = controller;
        if(ctrl.getSelected().size()==0)
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.info, 'Please Select atleast one Record to Export'));
    }
    public PageReference Export(){
        List<Id> objAnyIDs = new List<Id>();
        //system.debug(ctrl.getSelected()); 
        try{
            if (ctrl.getSelected().size()>0) {
                for(sObject sObj : ctrl.getSelected()) {
                    objAnyIDs.add(sObj.Id);
                }
                AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl.exportMultipleToExcel(objAnyIDs);
            }
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, ' Your Request is processed.'));
        } catch(system.Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ' There is an Error'));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
@isTest 
public class AnalyzeObjMultiExportCtrlExtTestClass
{
    static testMethod void constructorTest() 
    {
        Object_Analysis__c objAna = new Object_Analysis__c();
        objAna.Name = 'Account test';
        objAna.Custom__c=True;
        insert objAna;

        Test.StartTest(); 
        PageReference myVfPage = Page.ObjectAnalysisMultiExport;
        Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
        ApexPAges.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(objAna);
        //AnalyzeObjMultiExportCtrlExt testController = new AnalyzeObjMultiExportCtrlExt(sc);

        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your class you are using `ApexPages.StandardSetController` but in test class doing  `ApexPAges.StandardController`. try this intead

**Sample code**

```
@isTest 
public class TestStandardSetController 
{
 static testMethod void testMethod1() 
 {
 List <Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();

 Account testAccount = new Account();
 testAccount.Name='Test Account' ;
 lstAccount.add(testAccount);
 Account testAccount1 = new Account();
 testAccount1.Name='Test Account1' ;
 lstAccount.add(testAccount1);

 insert  lstAccount;

 Test.startTest();
  Test.setCurrentPage(Page.YOUR_PAGE);
  ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(lstAccount);
  stdSetController.setSelected(lstAccount);
  YOUR_Extension ext = new YOUR_Extension(stdSetController);
 Test.stopTest();
 }
}
```

. Try to create `StandardSetController`.

Comment: @user27639 If it solve your problem. Then you can mark this answer as accepted and close this question.